# Is it Possible to Hide an Object in Only One Viewport?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I have two viewports side by side.  The one on the left is always set to Rendered mode and seen through the active camera, while the one on the right is used for modeling.  This helps, of course, see the final result while I'm modeling.

But I frequently encounter objects in the foreground that I have to hide from view in order to model from that perspective.  But that object also hides from the rendered view, which I don't want.

Is there a way to just hide the object from view in one viewport and not the other?

Or to hide it from Solid view but not from Rendered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with *Local Collections*.
Simply put your foreground objects into a different collection, and then:

1. In *Sidebar (<kbd>N</kbd>) > View > Collections*
2. Check *Local Collections*
3. Pick which collections you want to see

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! Total game changer for me, I had no idea the Local Collections option was there.  Cheers.

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

On windows, the "/" key solos an object in the viewport. When I do this in one viewport, it hides the rest of the objects without changing their visibility in a different viewport. The monkey should be blocking the camera view, but on the left viewport i have solo'd the cube. Hope this helps!

EDIT:
Courtesy of Gordon Brinkmann, it should be noted that this will hide all objects in the view layer. If you want to solo multiple objects, you can select multiple objects before hitting "/". You could also select whatever object you specifically want to hide, inverting the selection with **Control + I** and then using "/" to solo everything except the object you desire to hide.
[image]

Comment: That's what I would have suggested, too. Although Glen might want to keep more objects visible than just one, perhaps if he needs to model something referencing something else. But the good thing is which should be added to this answer, the _Local_ view as it is called can be entered with multiple objects selected, not exclusively one "solo" object. Or to keep all except for one, he could select that, invert the selection with Ctrl+I and then enter _Local_ view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it.  Actually this is what I currently do and was hoping for a better way.  Jachym's answer below is more specifically to the point of what I want.

Comment: @GlenCandle Ah okay, didn't know that's what you're looking for. I usually put objects into collections to group them by either functionality (for example assembly groups of a machine etc.) or object type (like cameras, lights etc.) so while I'm modeling different parts of different collections might be obstructing the view and so I would find it more tedious to put them additionally into sepcific local collections as well. And I find it quicker to just select and hit / when some objects are in the way.